# Sometimes give an error updating value on Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I executed a query that update the whole database (with some restricts) with `status = 1`, and get the following errors:

1st time executing:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (SQL: update [example] set [status] = 1, [updated_at] = 2020-11-26 14:13:38.1000 where [exampleId] = 1251)
```

2nd time executing:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (SQL: update [example] set [status] = 1, [updated_at] = 2020-11-26 14:14:47.1000 where [exampleId] = 758)
```

3rd time executing:

```
No errors.
```

---

It seems to be something about the `updated_at` column, but I don't change that value manually.

---

The update function:

```
$example= $this->dbExample->where(...)->first();
$example->status = true;
$example->save();
```

The Model class:

```
class Example extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    
    protected $table = 'example';
    protected $primaryKey = 'exampleId';
    protected $fillable = [...];
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'status', 'updated_at'];

}
```

How can I solve this?

---

Edit 1:

It always give error on a timestamp that ends with `.1000`.

Comment: We're missing a lot of informations here, perhaps you could give us the code you used to update? the model of the table you're trying to update?

Comment: The date probably needs to be in quotes

Comment: @MarwaneEzzaze added.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: @sta yes, im using.

Comment: Add this line on your model `protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';` let me know if it worked  I am not sure it will 'Y-m-d H:i:s' or 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u0' or 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u',  but one should work I believe

Comment: Did you try this, any update?

Comment: @sta sorry for the late answer, none of them worked, but your comment gave me the idea of using `protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.000';` which seems to be working. thanks!

Comment: Add an answer, that will be helpful for future reader

Comment: I'll keep tracking the logs, if it doesn't give more errors, I will.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding #dates array to your model :

```
class Example extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    
    protected $table = 'example';
    protected $primaryKey = 'exampleId';
    protected $fillable = [...];
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'status', 'updated_at'];
    protected $dates = [
        'updated_at',
        'created_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

}
```

Comment: `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (SQL: update [example] set [status] = 1, [updated_at] = 2020-11-26 14:55:57.1000 where [exampleId] = 1293)`